# Android popup on screen from missed call broadcast receiver

Tags: java, android, popup, calllog

In my application i need to show a popup on screen when user got missed call, for that i wrote a receiver its working fine but when i try to display popup it shows an exception

```
06-30 15:24:11.320: E/AndroidRuntime(21759): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
06-30 15:53:20.883: E/AndroidRuntime(22873):    at com.ieltsdialer.receiver.MissedCallReceiver.initMissedCallPopup(MissedCallReceiver.java:96)
06-30 15:53:20.883: E/AndroidRuntime(22873):    at com.ieltsdialer.receiver.MissedCallReceiver$CustomPhoneStateListener.onCallStateChanged(MissedCallReceiver.java:83)
```

how can i call a popup from my receiver? or is there any other alternative to show popup?

MissedCallReceiver.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.ieltsdialer.R;
import com.ieltsdialer.common.SlidingPanel;

public class MissedCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{


    private static final String TAG = "BroadcastReceiver";  
    Context mContext;  
    String incoming_nr;  
    private int prev_state;  
    private Animation animShow, animHide;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); //TelephonyManager object  
        CustomPhoneStateListener customPhoneListener = new CustomPhoneStateListener();  
        telephony.listen(customPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE); //Register our listener with TelephonyManager  
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();  
        String phoneNr= bundle.getString("incoming_number");  
        Log.v(TAG, "phoneNr: "+phoneNr);  
        mContext=context;  
    }

    /* Custom PhoneStateListener */  
    public class CustomPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener{

        private static final String TAG = "CustomPhoneStateListener";  

        @Override  
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber){  

            if(incomingNumber!=null&&incomingNumber.length()>0) incoming_nr=incomingNumber;   
            switch(state){  
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:

                    Log.d(TAG, "CALL_STATE_RINGING");  
                    prev_state=state;  

                break;  

                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:  

                    Log.d(TAG, "CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK");  
                    prev_state=state;  

                break;  

                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:  

                    Log.d(TAG, "CALL_STATE_IDLE==>"+incoming_nr);  
                    if((prev_state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK)){  

                        prev_state=state;  
                        //Answered Call which is ended
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "answered call end", 5).show();

                    }  

                    if((prev_state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING)){  

                        prev_state=state;  
                        //Rejected or Missed call  
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, " missed call end"+incomingNumber, 5).show();
                        initMissedCallPopup();

                    }  

                break;  
            }  
        }  
    }

    public void initMissedCallPopup() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final SlidingPanel popup = (SlidingPanel) ((Activity) mContext).findViewById(R.id.popup_window);


        animShow = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation( mContext, R.anim.popup_show);
        animHide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation( mContext, R.anim.popup_hide);

        final ImageButton   hideButton = (ImageButton) ((Activity) mContext).findViewById(R.id.hide_popup_button);

        popup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        popup.startAnimation( animShow );
        hideButton.setEnabled(true);

        hideButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                popup.startAnimation( animHide );
                hideButton.setEnabled(false);
                popup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }});

        final TextView appName = (TextView) ((Activity) mContext).findViewById(R.id.app_name);
        final TextView description = (TextView) ((Activity) mContext).findViewById(R.id.missed_call_description);

        appName.setText("App Title");
        description.setText("Missed call Description");

    }

}
```

SlidingPanel.java

```
public class SlidingPanel extends LinearLayout 
{ 
    private Paint   innerPaint, borderPaint ;

    public SlidingPanel(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public SlidingPanel(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        innerPaint = new Paint();
        innerPaint.setARGB(100, 25, 25, 75); //gray
        innerPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        borderPaint = new Paint();
        borderPaint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
        borderPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        borderPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        borderPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    }

    public void setInnerPaint(Paint innerPaint) {
        this.innerPaint = innerPaint;
    }

    public void setBorderPaint(Paint borderPaint) {
        this.borderPaint = borderPaint;
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        RectF drawRect = new RectF();
        drawRect.set(0,0, getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());

        canvas.drawRoundRect(drawRect, 5, 5, innerPaint);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(drawRect, 5, 5, borderPaint);

        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please also mention the line, where the exception is thrown?

Comment: Yes, i updated my question @Prerak Sola It's at animShow = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation( mContext, R.anim.popup_show);

Comment: Can you also show your import statements? I think, you might have imported the class from wrong package.

Comment: please check it once, updated question with imports

Answer (score 0):

Your initMissedCallPopup method is not correct.

First:

```
final SlidingPanel popup = (SlidingPanel) ((Activity) mContext).findViewById(R.id.popup_window);
```

gives you an exception because mContext is not Activity but android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext (exception message very clearly shows that). You are assigning this variable in onReceive.
You have to find some way to obtain reference to activity that contains SlidingPanel.

Comment: Exactly @Okas could you please help me to find the way to obtain reference to activity that contains SlidingPanel.

Comment: This would be outside of this question scope. Try to find a solution and if you can not, then formulate a new question.